# Automatic organization of confirmations/rejections in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

I need to manage better my email into Gmail. I can receive two possible email messages: one for confirmation and the latter for rejection. A rejection email will come after a previous confirmation.

Basically, when I receive a confirmation email (the term confirmation is enclosed within the email text) I should organize that email in a dedicated folder 'Confirmation' (with a label). When I receive a rejection I should organize the rejection email with rejection label **and delete the related confirmation**.

The text in bold is the most important part that I don't know how to address.

Is it possible with Gmail, perhaps with a Google script?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, you can't do what you want with Gmail filters alone. You can organize the various messages, but there's no way to get Gmail to automatically delete a *different* email message with a filter.

There *may* be a third-party add-on that will do something like this, but asking (and answering) questions for recommendations is beyond this site's scope.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you think it possible by mking use of Google GMAIL API?

Comment: Maybe, but then that's a programming problem, and similarly off-topic here.